# How to remove trailing hamburger in appbar that is added automatically for endDrawer

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scaffold with an `endDrawer` where I have added a custom icon to open the endDrawer, however, the automatic hamburger icon for the end drawer is appearing and I can't figure out how to remove it. All the answers I am finding are for removing the leading one which does not help me with removing the trailing one. Thanks in advance. Below is the code I have

```
Scaffold(
        endDrawer: SafeArea(
                  child: Drawer(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(child: Text('Trial'),),
                Container(height:54, child: Text('New'),),
                Container(height:54, child: Text('Profile'),),
                Container(height:54, child: Text('Users List'),),
                Container(height:54, child: Text('Add User'),),
                Container(height:54, child: Text('About'),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: 'logo',
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/Logo.png'),
                  height: 36,
                  width: 59,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'NOTICES',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xAA243782),
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Orbitron'),
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  color: Color(0xAA243782),
                  size: 33,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context)openEndDrawer();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Color(0xAAAB8B3F2),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Trial'),
          ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1 : You need to use `actions: [Container()]` 
Step 2 : You need to use `GlobalKey` to open `End Drawer`

code snippet
     final globalKey = GlobalKey();

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [Container()],             

 onTap: () {                     
                  globalKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
        endDrawer: SafeArea(
          child: Drawer(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Text('Trial'),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 54,
                  child: Text('New'),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 54,
                  child: Text('Profile'),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 54,
                  child: Text('Users List'),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 54,
                  child: Text('Add User'),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 54,
                  child: Text('About'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [Container()],
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: 'logo',
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/Logo.png'),
                  height: 36,
                  width: 59,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'NOTICES',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xAA243782),
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: 'Orbitron'),
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  color: Color(0xAA243782),
                  size: 33,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  //Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                  globalKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Color(0xAAAB8B3F2),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Trial'),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected. I appreciate the help.